# VS2010 MultiProject Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, projects-and-solutions

How do I add a specific, NON-PROJECT Folder to a MultiProjectTemplate?

I.e I add a projectCollection to TemplateContent with all of my involved projects as ProjectTempateLink s inside.

How do I add a non-project related folder?

I've tried Folder both inside TemplateContent and inside a Project inside TemplateContent, but it doesn't work.

Looking at the schema http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwkxbww4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx it should be supported? Or is there an issue with using ProjectCollection and another tag inside TemplateContent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much solved, as a workaround made:

I made a blank C# project, included the files necessary.
I then made a single project-template of this, then added it to my multi-project template.
It's silly that It's not possible to add a non-project related folder, but hey...